# Send and Receive guaranteed bits at correct times using timer - 8051

Tags: assembly, byte, signals, 8051, debouncing

Not sure how to word the title, but this is my problem.

I'm making lazer tag and currently each vest has multiple hit points. In code, I call it streams.

What I want to do is that during game play:

1. Each vest will scan its streams or hit points to see if an attempted shot is about to begin. Once the first bit of the shot is detected, then the stream scanning is suspended until all of the bits of the shot have arrived. Then the value is scanned with another constant value to determine if the shot is legit or if some noise got into the system in which case the shot is invalid and ignored.
2. Each vest will have a function that constantly goes through each number from 1 to the maximum number of players. Personally I don't care if numbers go forward or backward or whatever way, as long as each player number is dealt with on a constant basis.
3. An external pin will define when the player is ready to make a shot. The shot (transmit) cannot happen until the function sets the number to the same player. Then all the data gets transmitted out all at once and then the shot is complete.

This is my code so far:

```
  TXDP equ P3.1 ;pin to output data on
  LCTR equ 30h ;data selector counter
  MYDATA equ 31h ;data to send out
  LI1 equ P3.5 ;bit to select data
  LI2 equ P3.5 ;bit to select data

  timer_interrupt:
    ;Save registers
    push ACC
    push PSW
    ;R7 = player# from 1 to MAX
    djnz R7,notstart
      mov R7,#MAX
    notstart:
    ;Send out my data one bit at a time
    ;if current player number is me
    cjne R7,#ME,notme
      mov A,MYDATA
        jz nodato 
          ;As data is sent, 0's fill in and MYDATA eventually becomes 0.
          clr C
          rrc A
          mov MYDATA,A
          mov TXDP,C
        nodato:
    notme:
    ;Start the receiving process if flag is set
    jnb STARTB,rcvst
      ;?? something needs to go here ??
      clr STARTB
      ;?? and here ??
      sjmp exittimer
    rcvst:
    ;At this point we move on to the next stream
    acall selectnextstream  
    ;And see if there is incoming data
    jb RCVP,norcv
      ;there is, so set the flag
      setb STARTB
    norcv:
    exittimer:
    ;restore registers
    pop PSW
    pop ACC
  reti

  selectnextstream:
    inc LCTR
    mov A,LCTR
    rrc A
    mov LI1,C
    rrc A
    mov LI2,C
  ret
```

and my biggest problem is getting #3 to work successfully.

The thing is a shot cannot start halfway in when the player numbers match and then have the shot end when the next player number is set by the system because then if everyone wanted to make a shot, two shots will occur at once.

I cannot have two or more shots occurring at once as it will screw up the receivers.

Also, the reason why I'm using a lot of bits for data I/O is because I want to create a guarantee of data. Best way to define this is more like key debouncing (where if you press a button, the value isn't recognized until a long time later).

So rather than bits, I'm thinking creating a byte like this to constantly send out:

```
01111110
```

and for the receive side, expecting either of these values to qualify for a valid shot received:

```
00011000
00111100
01111110
```

But those are examples.

Also, Due to speed limitations of lazers, I cannot use the UART for data exchange.

What can I do in my code to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your architecture description. Does every vest have it's own controller? (I guess, obviously it has). Do you want to exchange data with what and why (during game), these things in early days did operate individually. IIRC, the weapon did shot laser of certain wavelength, so the friendly fire was not an issue, and otherwise if the vest received the hit, it made you "dead" for few seconds... can't recall how much of info they did store during game or even send during game, but I don't think they ever did need to communicate between two vests, surely not in synced way.

Comment: Makes me wonder, if the gun did send some actual bit stream through the shot light, if it would be possible to reliably receive + decode it on the vest, seems to me like few bits with well defined header/tail signal repeated inside the shot should be fast enough to be readable by vest, the problem may be if two guns shoot at the same receptor at the same time, then the signal will get messed up, but if that signal is short enough (like 10ms) and you add random pause in between, two or three may get in "together".